# Find the number of solutions of $x^2\equiv -2\pmod{61}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Find the number of solutions of $x^2\equiv \color{blue}{-2}\pmod{61}$

I am a bit confused If I should check Legendre symbol of $\left(\frac{\color{blue}{-2}}{61}\right)$ or Legendre symbol of $\left(\frac{D}{61}\right)$ where $D$ denotes the discriminant of the polynom $x^2+0\cdot x+\color{blue}2$,

i.e $D=0^2-4\cdot 1\cdot2=-8$

Comment: Legendre symbol only gives positive or negative result, i.e. exists or not exists solution. It does not count the solutions.

Comment: @user3313320 Yes it is, the number of solutions are $\left(\frac a p\right)+1$

Comment: Because $-8$ is gotten from $-2$ by multiplying it with a square, $-8=(-2)\cdot2^2$, we have
$$\left(\frac{-8}{61}\right)=\left(\frac{-2}{61}\right).$$ In other words, it doesn't matter which you calculate. The same applies to all congruences of the form $x^2\equiv a\pmod p$.

Comment: In that specific case $-8$ above $61$ equal to $-2$ above $61$, but is it always true? for $x^2\equiv \color{green}a \pmod p$ the number of solutions are $$\left( \frac {\color{green}a}{ p}\right)+1=\left(\frac {\color{red}D}{ p} \right)+1$$ @JyrkiLahtonen

Comment: Since it is always $D=4a$ (under your definition of $D$), they are always equal.

Comment: $x^2\equiv -2\pmod{61}$ has no solutions. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity#.C2.B12_and_the_second_supplement If $p$ is an odd prime, then $x^2\equiv -2\pmod{p}$ has a solution if and only if $p\equiv 1,3\pmod{8}$. In this case, $61\equiv 5\pmod{8}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $61\equiv 5\pmod{8}$, $-1$ is a quadratic residue $\!\!\pmod{61}$ but $2$ is not, so neither is $-2$ and
$$ x^2\equiv -2\pmod{61}$$
has no solutions.